# How does PIL handle a numpy matrix with negative values?

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to build a machine learning model, and in the first step, I plan to convert my data matrix (consisting of real numbers, both positive and negative values) into RGB images. All of these values are smaller than 255. I know we can do that with the PIL package, but I wonder if the original negative values can still be retained if we make them into images? Or they will be all rounded to zero?

I went through so many google examples, but still confused. So I am asking to be certain.

Comment: Try it and see what happens. And post it here because I am interested too and voted and bookmarked your question

Comment: If we use grayscale, the original data values will be kept. I don't know how well the ML model can differentiate grayscale images though. If we use RGB, all the values will be converted to RGB values (i.e between 0-255).

Comment: Are the images real images or just data representation ? Can you use 16 or 32 bit grayscale ?? Just get the minimum and maximum values of your data convert them and compare to the min e max pixel values of the images obtained